Can I get InputDocument type after upload file to Telegram servers?
Telethon 1.36.0
Python 3.12.4
upload = await client.upload_file(request, file_name="gif.mp4")
print(type(upload))
<class 'telethon.tl.custom.inputsizedfile.InputSizedFile'>

Can I use the constructor to make an InputDocument type from an uploaded file?
I need this type to get:

id

access_hash

file_reference


Please do not offer me options for sending this document to the chat.
InputDocument after uploaded file.

You can use UploadMediaRequest. In v1:
from telethon import functions, types, utils

document = await client(functions.messages.UploadMediaRequest(
    peer='me',
    media=types.InputMediaUploadedDocument(
        file=await client.upload_file('/path/to/file.gif'),
        mime_type='image/gif',
        attributes=[],
    ),
))
print(document.stringify())  # MessageMediaDocument
input_document = utils.get_input_media(document)  # InputMediaDocument

Even though you must specify a peer, this won't actually send it.
